# type '(SearchOkResponse) => Iterable<EffectWithResult>' is not a subtype of type '(IOkResponse) => Iterable<dynamic>'

Tags: dart

Всем доброго времени суток!)

Есть базовый класс IOkResponse:

```
class IOkResponse {}
```

Есть 2 класса, которые его реализуют - SearchOkResponse и MovieOkResponse. Например, SearchOkResponse:

```
class SearchOkResponse implements IOkResponse {
  final List<Map<String, String>> data;
  final int totalResults;

  const SearchOkResponse(this.data, this.totalResults);

  @override
  String toString() {
    return '''SearchOkResponse{
        data: $data,
        totalResults: $totalResults,
      }''';
  }
}
```

Использую Redux (перехожу с React Native, решил переходить постепенно, поэтому не блок) и redux-saga. Хочу написать сагу для обработки ответов от апишки. Сага выглядит так:

```
Iterable successResponseHandler({
  @required dynamic response,
  @required Iterable Function(IOkResponse apiResponse) onSuccess,
  @required Function(FailedResponse apiResponse) onFailed,
}) sync* { /* code */ }
```

При передаче для параметра onSuccess следующей саги:

```
(SearchOkResponse response) sync* { /* code */ }
```

получаю ошибку, указанную в заголовке: `type '(SearchOkResponse) => Iterable<EffectWithResult>' is not a subtype of type '(IOkResponse) => Iterable<dynamic>'`.
Если в объявлении саги `successResponseHandler` для параметра `onSuccess` тип `IOkResponse` поменять на `SearchOkResponse`, то ошибки не будет. Но мне надо, чтобы `onSuccess` принимал другую сагу, которая принимает при вызове класс, который реализует класс `IOkResponse`.

Пожалуйста, объясните причину ошибки и как это можно исправить.
Заранее благодарю за помощь)

Comment: А покажите как вы взываете (что передаете) `onSuccess` в `successResponseHandler`. И еще один момент: а не проще вам использовать тут `generics`?

Comment: Туда я передаю это

`Function onSearchSuccess(success) {
  return ((SearchOkResponse response) sync* {
    /* обработка результата */

    yield Put(success(movies, isThatsAll));
  });
}`

Передаю так: `onSuccess: onSearchSuccess(
          (movies, isThatsAll) => FetchMoreSuccessAction(movies, isThatsAll)),`

Comment: По поводу generics думал, но просто хотелось бы понять, почему тут ругается. Кстати, если в `@required Iterable Function(IOkResponse apiResponse) onSuccess` поставить SearchOkResponse вместо IOkResponse, то я смогу передать туда функцию, которая принимает SearchOkResponse или IOkResponse.

Comment: В вашем случае `IOkResponse` это интерфейс, тогда сделайте его абстрактным. И все таки попробуйте через `generics` (`<T extends IOkResponse>`).